# How to compare two or more strings and return single value from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table called `messages`

In that I have a three columns columns

1. Id
2. number
3. message

In `number` column I have inserted below data

```
 Number           Messages
-------------------------
123456789         Hi
678901111         Hello
+91123456789      Hi
+915678901111     Hello
```

When I use query

```
Select distinct(right(col2,10) as col2 from message;
```

I want my results as

```
Number           Messages
-------------------------
123456789         Hi
678901111         Hello
```

This is what I am trying to achieve
How can I make `123456789` return only one

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will return an unpredictable result in older MySQL versions, will raise an error in new versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text tables. (Not images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from sample data, that you need a `distinct` list of last `9` digits from `number` column and `message` column as it is, You can use `right` and `distinct` functions to generate your desired result as below.

```
SELECT distinct(right(number,9)) AS number,
       message
FROM t1
```

The above query will work in both `character` and `integer` data types.

**Result:**

```
number     message
------------------
123456789   hi
678901111   hello
```

You can check the demo [**here**](http://rextester.com/GBC58213)

Comment: Not working bro,  when I use this it shows two results

Comment: @user8515823: Can you kindly share your desired output?  I have simulated the sample data you posted in question and shared the results.  You can check demo included in answer.

Comment: when +91234567890 it shows 234567890 but for 1234567890 it shows some results... I want my results as when there is a two same numbers such as +917904621001 and 7904621001 (number -column), and (message- column)  'hi' & 'hello' as two message I want to return only one number and two messages  as 7904621776 (hi, hello)...

Comment: Is the length fixed? for `number` with `+` `13` and without `10`? Kindly add full sample data and your desired result. I will modify the answer accordingly as currently your question is not clear.

Comment: I have updated the question set please see there I have mentioned my output format

Comment: That was perfect, got working solution... thank you so much